# cant read input type text value from jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to read value from

```
<input type="text" value="test" id="userid_from_tasks[<?php echo $i_tasks;?>]" />
```

$i_tasks is a counter in php mysql while, so it can be 0,1 etc.

in jquery i cant set value to this field

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#userid_from_tasks')(0).val('test1'));    
    alert($('#userid_from_tasks')(1).val('test2'));     
});
```

the point is i cant set (0),(1) values

Comment: I think you should use square brackets instead of circular to reference index. For ex:  alert($('#userid_from_tasks') **[** 0 **]** .val('test1'));

Comment: you want to get the the values or you want to set the values?

Comment: @KaranDesai an Id is unique and the number added by php is another id...

Comment: i want to set values to userid_from_tasks input type

Comment: @perastikos1 look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

First you are assigning value to input not reading to read just `$('input').val()`

the id which you are looking fore doesn't exist, I suggest you to add a class to inputs then loop throught them

```js
$('.input').each(function(){
console.log($(this).val());

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" value="test" id="userid_from_tasks[<?php echo $i_tasks;?>]" />

<input type="text" class="input" value="test" id="userid_from_tasks[<?php echo $i_tasks;?>]" />
```

Comment: the point is i want to set value to this field id="userid_from_tasks[<?php echo $i_tasks;?>]" . field exists but the problem is i cant set value to [0] or [1] etc

Comment: @perastikos1 so you only write : $('#userid_from_tasks1').val('test2')

Comment: i write this : $('#userid_from_tasks1')(0).val('test2') but its not working, it doesnt recognize the (0). if i write $('#other_field').val('test2') for another field that its single, not (0) or (1) it works

Comment: because (0) means nothing you only write that $('#userid_from_tasks1').val('test2')

Comment: so i cant set values to repeated text value?

Comment: the number you are adding is in the id so you write like that $('#userid_from_tasks1').val('test2')  $('#userid_from_tasks2').val('test2') $('#userid_from_tasks3').val('test2') ....

Comment: the id #userid_from_tasks doesn't exist you are writing a new id everytime, also note that you cant use id like that it's unique

Comment: You could concatenate the id: `$('#userid_from_tasks' + 1).val('test2')`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: concatination its not working, $('#userid_from_tasks' + 0).val('test2'); it doesnt set the value

Comment: I suggest that you first log the object you're getting to console, to see if you're actually getting the object you want.

Comment: oh wait... I just noticed you're using [] brackets in your id name. why?

Comment: @nGAGE yes.. I think he is expecting that he can use it as an array

Comment: He'll have to lose the brackets. Don't think that's a valid ID name.

Comment: thanks all, the problem was i had id="userid_from_tasks[<?php echo $i_tasks;?>]"  but the correct is id="userid_from_tasks<?php echo $i_tasks;?>" with no [] brackets